# Get substring from some char inside string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am trying to get substring ie address from the below string

```
string test = "name: abc loc: xyz address: tfd details: ddd";
```

Is there any substring option to get only address details like "tfd"

I am trying by splitting and I think this is not the best option to get middle string.

```
test.Text.Split(':').LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) FTW!

Comment: Is it always "tfd"? Is it always the value after "address:"? We need more info.

Comment: Just checking: Your data looks suspiciously like a json string stripped of braces, commas and quotes. If so: de-serialize to an object instead of fiddling with strings.

Comment: this is a string and not json. My dynamic string looks like json but not.

Answer (score 3):

Simple function:

```
public static string GetTextBetween(string content, string start, string end)
{
    if (content.Length == 0 || start.Length == 0 || end.Length == 0)
        return string.Empty;
    string contentRemove = content.Remove(0, content.IndexOf(start, StringComparison.Ordinal) + start.Length);
    return contentRemove.Substring(0, contentRemove.IndexOf(end, StringComparison.Ordinal)).Trim();
}
```

Example:

```
GetTextBetween("name: abc loc: xyz address: Thomas Nolan Kaszas 5322 Otter LnMiddleberge FL 32068 details: ddd", "address:", "details:")
```

And you will get:

> Thomas Nolan Kaszas 5322 Otter LnMiddleberge FL 32068

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach with regular expressions:

```
var pattern = @"name: (\S+) loc: (\S+) address: (\S+) details: (\S+)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var group = match.Groups[3];
var value = group.Value;
```

A few assumptions:

- The address will always be one word, i.e. no spaces,
- The pattern will always be the same, same fields, in the same order, no difference in case in the field names, etc.

Comment: Not sure it's safe to assume an address wouldn't have a space in it.

Comment: @juharr -- that's why I put it in the "assumptions".  He can take it or leave it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts = test.split(' ');
var keyIndex = parts.indexOf('address:');
var address = parts[keyIndex + 1];
```

Comment: Works with the example, but fails if the address has a space in it like say "123 Maple Street".

Comment: @juharr -- That's why you have to enforce some rules.

Comment: The question did not mention spaces and example did not have them.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the Regex solutions more, but I want to add a Non-regex one:

```
string test = "name: abc loc: xyz address: t f d details: ddd";
int start = test.IndexOf("address:");
int end = test.IndexOf("details:");
string adr = test.Substring(start, end-start);
Console.WriteLine(adr);
```

prints

```
t f d
```

So I know this version works with spaces.

Edit:

You may want to run `adr.Trim()` or modify the strings in the two `IndexOf` calls to cut out the spaces on either side of the returned string.

Comment: So, what if the address itself is "details:"?

Comment: Then it doesn't work.  It looks like the OP is using keywords ending with ':' to identify parts of the data and not the data itself, so it should be safe.  I don't know this for sure though, so it is just another option for OP if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use some Regex pattern that fits your needs as suggested

```
Match m = new Regex( @"address:\s(.*)\sdetails" ).Match( test );
if ( m.Groups.Count > 0 )
    { string s = m.Groups[1].Value; }
```